# Pausing/Resuming a Loop in Excel VBA (on Click)

Tags: excel, vba, button, resume, pause

So, I'm working with a rather large Excel sheet. I have created a lot of functions as it is fairly complex. When I tell it to Execute it takes quite a long time. I have created a timer that tells one how fare into the process it has come (illustrated on the picture):

[image: Screenshot of Counter]

Now. I would very much like to make a pause button. I have tried with:

```
Private Sub PauseButton_Click()
Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:20")
End Sub
```

Which actually does pause the process. My initial thought was to enter a very large number and then resume on a button click. Unfortunately I can't resume (`DoEvents`) the process, as Excel seems compleatly frozen for the period entered.

If you have any ideas about how to fix this, they would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: To "pause" is not an easy task as you may think. First of: `Application.Wait` will always freeze the application (as you have noticed). To do it as you want it, you would need to skip/end the sub and restart it on resume. Having one or more (global/static) variables which tell the process where to "resume" (simply to not start at the beginning) will give the "feeling" of a pause. But this would need you to change bigger parts of your code... you could simulate a pause with a `DoEvents` loop, but this may crash if you try to do something with the sheet ending up with a new start from 0%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, concerning that we do not have a view of the code of the form, you may try declaring a public boolean `b_pause`, which tells you whether you are paused or not. And write something like this:

```
public b_pause as boolean

sub RunMe
    b_pause = True
    Do While b_pause
        DoEvents
    Loop
End sub

Sub StopMe()
    b_pause = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It makes good sense, I can add the condition in my two large loops and make it check the value after each iteration. Though, where do I declare a public boolean? In a new module as a sub (fx sub declarePublics) ?

Comment: Public variables are declared outside functions and sub. Depending on the way you code, it is probably a good idea, to make a module, where you only declare public variables, without any subs and functions there.

Comment: It works like a charm! Though the function RunMe actually pauses the program while the StopMe resumes. Not sure why, but I triple checked everything, and honestly what matters is that it works. So thank you a LOT! And if anyone should ever need this post, then the boolean has to be defined as `public b_pause as Boolean`. No biggie though.

Comment: Changed the boolean definition on the top. Actually, public variables are considered bad practise in programming, just fyi. :)